# MySQL workbench granting permission to another user

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing a issue while granting privileges a user to another user in MySQL workbench.
Let I have two users " admin , driver"
And I have been granting some privileges both of them.

Now I have created a new user by
" Create user 'one'@localhost identified by 'one' "
I want to copy/ give all permissions of user driver to user one.

Anyone can help me.